# How to make sure an item doesn't get pushed into an array twice?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to display four random images on my page, therefore first I am creating a random image from an initial array of images:

```
function randomFlag() {
var randomFlag = Math.floor(Math.random() * flags.length);
return flags[randomFlag];
}
```

Then I am pushing four random images into a new array:

```
function generateRandomFlag(num) {
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    arr.push(randomFlag());
}
return arr;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that sometimes I am getting the same image pushed twice into the array and eventually having two or more of the same image displayed instead of having four random Images.

How can I create the functionality to first check if the image already exists in the array, and push it only if it doesn't exist there already?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `.indexOf()` or `.includes()` to test if an item is already in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative approach is to use all flags, shuffled randomly

```
function generateRandomFlag(num) {
    return flags
    .slice() // copy the flags array because .sort mutates the source array
    .sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; }) // shuffle the copied array
    .slice(-num); // get the LAST "num" values of the shuffled array
}
```

In ES2015+ it's even more succinct

```
const generateRandomFlag = num => flags.slice().sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5).slice(-num);
```

Comment: That's a weird shuffle. I generally use `return Math.random() - 0.5`?

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I have tried that, however I am getting the same four images over and over again. Any other suggestions I can try?

Comment: please see revised code - I derped the derp in the sort function :p

Comment: Sorry, previous comment deleted, it didn't make sense. Yes, Floor(rnd * 3) -1 makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could either refactor `generateRandomFlag` or `randomFlag`. In my case I will refactor `generateRandomFlag`.

```
function generateRandomFlag(num) {
  var arr = [];
  var reachNum = false;
  var ctr=0;
  while (!reachNum) {
    var flag = randomFlag();
    if (arr.indexOf(flag)==-1)
    {
      arr.push(flag);    
      ctr++;
    }
    if (ctr==num)
       reachNum = true;
  }
 return arr;
}
```